# Compact way to get potential captures in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, capture

I want to iterate over some lines of text and do the following:

```
caps = /something(.*)to capture/.match(line).captures
do_something_with_caps(caps[0])
```

But I'll get the `Undefined method 'captures' for nil:NilClass` whenever I don't get a match.  I can assign the match to a temporary variable, and then test for `nil` before getting the capture, but that seems quite verbose to me.  Is there a more compact way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `.match.captures` with [`.scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) as an alternative:

```
caps = line.scan(/something(.*)to capture/).flatten
do_something_with_caps(caps[0])
```

Examples:

```
'somethingabcdto capture'.scan(/something(.*)to capture/).flatten #=> ["abcd"]
'nothing to capture here'.scan(/something(.*)to capture/).flatten #=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
caps = $~.captures if /something(.*)to capture/.match(line)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.